# ZK :Show Bind value in Client.showNotification

Tags: mvvm, zk

i m working on a ZK project using MVVM aproach , what i m trying to do is to show notification of a @bind(each.info) value but is not seems to work with me , here s what i have done so far.

```
<div width="59%"  style=" float: left !important;" apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
  viewModel="@id('menu') @init('ma.schlemmer.headerbar.mainMenu')">


    <hlayout children="@bind(menu.listMenu)">
            <template name="children">
                     <a  iconSclass="@bind(each.icon)"  href="@bind(each.link)" autag="@bind(each.info)" onRightClick='Clients.showNotification("@bind(each.info)" ,"warning",this.self,"after_center",1000)'></a>
             </template>
     </hlayout>
</div>
```

and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using ZK commands. You should get the result you want like this:

```
<div width="59%"  style=" float: left !important;" apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
    viewModel="@id('menu') @init('ma.schlemmer.headerbar.mainMenu')">


<hlayout children="@bind(menu.listMenu)">
    <template name="children">
        <a  iconSclass="@bind(each.icon)"  href="@bind(each.link)" autag="@bind(each.info)"
            onRightClick="@command('showInfo', obj=each, comp=self)"></a>
         </template>
 </hlayout>
```

Then add this command to your View Model:

```
@Command
public void showInfo(@BindingParam("obj") ListMenu listMenu, @BindingParam("comp") Component comp) {
    Clients.showNotification(listMenu.getInfo(),"warning",comp,"after_center",1000);
}
```

You did not provide enough code, so I can`t test the exact situation, but basically you need to pass the object each (which I guess is something like ListMenu object) and component to the command. Then you can easily show notification.

Best regards,
Osvaldas